# Add string to selected property of ad-user

Tags: powershell, active-directory

How can I add the text "test" to the end of the HomeDrive-Path for each selected user ?

```
Get-ADUser -filter * -properties EmailAddress, HomeDirectory -SearchBase "OU=Teacher,OU=__User Accounts,DC=school,DC=local" | 
    select EmailAddress, HomeDirectory |
    ConvertTo-Csv | 
    Out-File c:\temp\teacher.csv
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use select Expression:

```
Get-ADUser -filter * -properties EmailAddress, HomeDirectory -SearchBase "OU=Teacher,OU=__User Accounts,DC=school,DC=local" | 
    select EmailAddress, @{l="HomeDirectory"; e={"{0}test" -f $_.HomeDirectory}} |
    ConvertTo-Csv | 
    Out-File c:\temp\teacher.csv
```

Where "l" is the label of the new Property and "e" is the definition / expression of the property (In this case, its a format string)

Comment: Is it possible that you missed a } after f $_.HomeDirectory ?